# What is the default cursor set called in Ubuntu 20.04 onwards?

Tags: cursor

I've noticed a black cursor in Michael MJD's MS Edge for Linux video which has a white link select, and I was wondering if it was a custom set or a default set, thus coming to the conclusion that it's a default set, but I still don't know what is the default set even called, if it has a name.

Comment: Yeah on stock 20.04, my cursor is black when it's an arrow, and white when it's pointing to a link on a webpage. I have never even noticed it before. Anyways, Gnome Tweaks tells me it might be called the "Yaru" cursor theme. "Yaru" is also the name of Ubuntu 20.04's default (and only pre-installed) GTK desktop theme.

Answer (score 0):

The default cursor theme is called "Yaru".

It is located in `/usr/share/icons/Yaru/cursors`.

You can set/change the default cursor theme using Gnome Tweaks (installed using `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`).